# Recommended way to format copyright?

Tags: typography, style-manuals, cmos

I'm working on a website and want to have a short mention of the copyright of said website in its footer. What is the recommended formatting for such a thing?

I've seen "© YYYY Company", "© Company, YYYY", and other formats.

Do any style guides have recommendations for this? I'd be interested in the Chicago Manual of Style in particular, as that's the one I'm most comfortable with.

Comment: How are you using this? In a citation/reference (which CMOS probably would deal with) or within a book or article to cover the article itself? CMOS probably wouldn't cover the latter. Are you using it in a jurisdiction which mandates copyright notices to enforce copyright? What style guide does your publisher use?

Comment: Copyright notices are used in order to produce certain legal effects; if there were no copyright law, they would not exist. They should thus be formatted in whatever way will produce the intended legal effects, according to the laws of the relevant jurisdiction. This question is thus, effectively, a request for legal advice, and thus outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm using it on a website in a footer. Based on rajah9's answer, though, it seems that the CMoS recommendation is broad enough to apply here as well.

Comment: @jsw29 I've seen various different formats for the copyright line and I'm quite sure they're all equally legally valid. My question therefore truly only concerns stylistic recommendations. (And there, I truly doubt any prominent style guide's recommendations would fail to be legally valid.)

Comment: @tchrist You've just (correctly imo) migrated a question about spacing a symbol to Graphic Design. Aren't most typograohy-related questions a better fit there?

Answer (score 2):

*Chicago Manual of Style* (13th ed.), section 4.16 says:

> ...the notice consists of three parts: (1) the symbol © (preferred because it also suits the requirements of the Universal Copyright Convention), the word *Copyright*, or the abbreviation *Copr.*, (2) a date — the year of first publication, and (3) the name of the copyright owner. Most publishers also add the phrase *All rights reserved*...

So CMoS goes (mostly) with the first format, namely

> "© Copyright YYYY Company"

Comment: I've edited accordingly. If you have digital rights or a later print edition, please post an updated answer. .I'd like to see exactly what CMoS says, and how that has changed over time.

Comment: The order probably doesn't matter legally, as long as all the necessary elements are included.

Comment: Not everyone uses © or ®. Some just write out: All rights reserved.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for CMoS, @Lambie.

Comment: No, that is not accurate: Do any style guides have recommendations for this? Corporate usage is a style guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
From the text you posted, it seems like CMoS is encouraging using "© YYYY Company" OR "Copyright YYYY Company", not both. I've also seen Butterick discouraging the use of the symbol and the word being used together, as it's duplicative – https://practicaltypography.com/trademark-and-copyright-symbols.html.

Answer (score -1):

This is how some big boys do it:

COCA COLA
2020 The Coca-Cola Company. All Rights Reserved.

GENERAL ELECTRIC
© 2020 GENERAL ELECTRIC

CHASE BANK
© 2020 JPMorgan Chase & Co.

IBM
IBM®

IBM has a very interesting texts about their logos and how to use all of theirs.

I would not use the Chicago Manual of Style here. I would check other well-known companies in the same business as your own and follow what they do.

Anyway, what's good for the goose is not necessarily good for the gander. Use what you consider best based on that research on other companies.

[IBM logo and IBM-owned company logos](https://www.ibm.com/legal/copytrade)

Comment: While you might not agree with CMoS, let's not muddy the waters: ® is for a registered trademark, which has nothing to do with copyrights.

Comment: @rajah9 "Do any style guides have recommendations for this?" What companies actually do is a "**style guide" in the real world**. Yes, ok re the registered trademark but the idea is the same re style.